# Retrieve and Remove elements from string

Tags: c#

Say I have a list of string

```
List<string> lst=new List<string>(new string[]{"a","b","c","d"});
```

I wish to get element from index 0 to index 2 assign it to another List lst1(i.e. the element of lst  is `{"a","b"}`), then remove it from lst (i.e. lst becomes `{"c","d"}`， what's the quickest way of doing this? I am thinking is there any command like

```
List<string> lst=new List<string>();
lst1=lst.getElements(1,2);
lst.remove(1,2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [GetRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) to copy of a range of elements and [RemoveRange()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) to removes a range of elements.

**Example :**

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
List<string> lst1 = lst.GetRange(0, 2);
lst.RemoveRange(0, 2);
```

Good Luck !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) and [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx):

```
var range = lst.Take(2);
lst1.AddRange(range);
lst.RemoveRange(0, 2);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/1X2cV